# How do you indicate a Web Application vs Site Collection in for the -url parameter in PowerShell?

Tags: feature-activation

When I run the code script below:

```
enable-spfeature "MyFeature" –url "http://myportal:5555"
```

I get the error:

> This feature is not a farm level feature and is not found in a Site
>   level defined by the URL http://myportal.com:5555

Technically this is correct, but I wanted to enable the feature at the web application level. Is there a way to specifically indicate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature scope is defined within the feature definition, it is not set via PowerShell. If it is a Site level feature, then you will need to activate it individually for every site in your web application (if that's what you want).

Comment: I want to be able to activate it at the web application level. It's scoped at the web application level but when I enter the web application URL it seems to mistake it for a site collection URL.

Comment: When you type `Get-SPFeature "MyFeature"` what comes up under Scope?

Comment: It says Web which makes sense for the error but in the UI it shows up as a feature for the web application. Is there any reason why that might occur? I don't currently have the source code for this.